# history.push changes url but does not render form react hooks

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, forms

English is not my mother language so sorry for mistakes, i'm react beginner, my question:
I am at route /#/billingInfo/
when user clicks 'sender' button payers name will be senders name and same for 'receiver' button, but the problem is i'm pushing same url which is this same page, i get senders or receivers name in my input as i should but only when i refresh the page, my question is how to not refresh the page and get those in my input (need to  render/forceUpdate < Form > or that specific input when user clicks those buttons
??)

my code:

```
const [form] = Form.useForm();

  const query = window.location.toString().split("?")[1];

  const urlParamss = new URLSearchParams(query);

  const payer = new URLSearchParams(query).get("payer");
  const bNameUrl = urlParamss.get("bName");

  const PickUpName = urlParamss.get("pName");

  const DeliveryName = urlParamss.get("dName");

  let bName;

  if (payer === "sender") {
    bName = PickUpName;
  } else if (payer === "receiver") {
    bName = DeliveryName;
  }

  const senderPays = () => {
    history.push(`/billingInfo/${customerId}?${query}&payer=sender`);
  };

  const receiverPays = () => {
    history.push(`/billingInfo/${customerId}?${query}&payer=receiver`);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Form>
        <div>
          <Button onClick={senderPays}>sender</Button>
          <Button onClick={receiverPays}>receiver</Button>
        </div>
        <Form.Item
          label="payers name"
          name="bName"
          initialValue={bNameUrl || bName}
        >
          <Input type="string" />
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default BillingInfo;
```

Comment: You may need to use an `useEffect` with a dependency on the route path value to reset some state or form data. Can you clarify how your routes & component is rendered, and provide a complete react component that is rendering the form?

Comment: i'm using   const history = useHistory();

Comment: My guess is clicking your buttons will submit the form (i.e. refresh the page here), which you don't want. Use `const senderPays = (e) => {` instead and call `e.preventDefault();` before pushing to history.

Comment: Good call @ChrisG! Please check/ensure the `Button` components are not submitting the form and reloading the page on you.

Comment: @ChrisG it is currently working as it should but need to refresh the page in order to see those results in my input... i dont want user to refresh, i want them to appear there without refresh

Comment: @ChrisG i did it as you said but same result

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to use an `<input>` to display something to the user? Don't do that, just use a <span> or <p> or whatever. Also, and this is very basic React: if you want your HTML to show something different after a button click, you need to use the component's `state`. Use something like `const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState("sender");` to create a `state` variable, then call `setButtonText("new text");` in your button's onclick handler to change it. Use `{buttonText}` in your JSX to display it. Again, this is basic React stuff.

Comment: @ChrisG no there is two buttons and input is empty in the beginning, when user is at that stage user need to know who will pay, so user for example chooses that sender pays, he clicks sender button and then senders name will appear in input, then user continues...from here on that information which appears in input is needed in other pages

Comment: What you describes sounds like a very good candidate for local component state. Update the state from one input and when a button is clicked it populates another component with the value saved in state.

Comment: just need to render/forceUpdate that form after user clicks those buttons

Comment: Yes, and I just told you *exactly* how to do that. That is the core mechanism of React: 1) state changes 2) component re-renders

Comment: @DrewReese as you can see i'm getting those values from url at the moment

Comment: It also sounds like you are not really using React as intended but forcing a pseudo URL storage JS app into react components.

Comment: And that is why I asked about how this component's rendering relates to the URL and using an `useEffect` hook to "listen" for updates on any routing changes.

Comment: could you give working example ? using my code(from url)

Comment: That kind of depends on the working/reproducible example we're asking from you. What and how is this component being rendered? What, if any, routing/navigation library are you using? You mention `useHistory` so it seems `react-router-dom` is a safe assumption, but I prefer to work with facts/knowns over assumptions.

Comment: i'm using import { useHistory, useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";

Comment: and in my app.js(if this info is needed ) im using import {
  Redirect,
  Route,
  Switch,
  useHistory,
} from "react-router-dom";

Comment: When the buttons are clicked, what *actually* changes? Just the `payer` query string parameter?

Comment: it will add to the url '&payer=receiver' or '&payer=sender'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `payer` query parameter is the only difference in urls when the new routes are pushed, then you can "listen" for changes on that value in an `useEffect` hook.

1. Create a custom query parameter hook. From the React-Router docs [Query Parameters](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters).

   ```
   const useQuery = () => {
     return new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
   };
   ```
2. Use this hook to get the query parameters.

   ```
   const {
     payer,
     bName: bNameUrl,
     dName: DeliveryName,
     pName: PickUpName
   } = useQuery();
   ```
3. Move `bName` into component state.

   ```
   const [name, setName] = useState(bNameUrl || bName);
   ```
4. Use `useEffect` to handle any changes to `payer` and update `name` state.

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
     setName(payer === 'sender' ? PickUpName : DeliveryName);
   }, [payer]);
   ```
5. Render `name` as the default input value (*retains whatever form logic you may have*). Use a react key on the form to help "re-initialize" it by indicating to react it's a "new" component and needs to be mounted. See [Fully uncontrolled component with a key](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key).

   ```
   <Form key={name}>
     <div>
       <Button onClick={senderPays}>sender</Button>
       <Button onClick={receiverPays}>receiver</Button>
     </div>
     <Form.Item
       label="payers name"
       name="bName"
       initialValue={name}
     >
       <Input type="string" />
     </Form.Item>
   </Form>
   ```

Comment: this needs to be changed '  setName(payer === 'sender' ? PickUpName : DeliveryName);
' ?

Comment: @walee Are you able to extrapolate this pattern out to the other similar inputs? I don't see any of these other inputs or variables in your [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: got it working using your code, thanks a lot !